# Is it okay to eat meat from big industrial farms where animals are treated very poorly?

Tags: halal-haram, food, business, animals, meat

The animals in big industrial farms are treated very poorly. What is the Islamic view on this area, and is it OK to eat these products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In islam, all animals worship Allah and praise him, even if this praise is not known to human. Generally, a Mulsim should be kind to animals and any living (non-harmful) creature.

While the Prophet (PBUH) was with a companion of his, they entered a garden. The prophet saw a camel which came closer and started crying with tears. The prophet asked about his owner, and talked to him and blamed him for his cruelty against the camel. [Hadith Narrated by Abu-Dawood, certified by Al-Albany]

And there are more hadiths similar to that one.

Regarding the products from farmers who mistreat their animals, they do not become haram for their cruelty, the sin does not propagate. If their products are Halal, then it is still Halal, and they get the sin of their animals mistreating. If you can find similar products from farmers who honor animal rights, I think this is preferable.

Comment: By buying mistreated animals you are supporting the act of cruelty therefore embracing the sin, please support your answer with references.

Comment: Originally, every thing is not Haram, unless there's a Hadith/Quran stating so. People normally buy goods not to support its producers, but to fulfil their needs. This is not considered "supporting cruelty" nor "freeing the animals from cruelty".